# Python stop input after empty string is entered

Tags: python

Recently I started diving into python a bit, unfortunately I am struggling in the very beginning.
**What is the best and the most elegant way to abort user input after an empty string is entered?**

The approach I tried wont break the input no matter what I enter.

```
    def populate_list():
    list=[]
    while True:
        try:
            list.append(input("Enter values: "))
        except EOFError:
            break;
    return list
```

Comment: use `if` condition with `continue;`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're passing the result of `input()` directly into `append()`, with no intermediate step to check if it's empty.

You need to save the input in a separate variable and check if it's empty *before* appending it to your list.

Try this:

```
while True:
    answer = input("Enter values: ")
    if not answer:
        break
    lista.append(answer)
return lista
```

Comment: OP is using while loop there for `continue;` is better.

Comment: @Kalana If I use `continue`, this loop will never exit...

Comment: What if the input is `False`? It will break anyway. What if `False` is a valid input? This will not work.

Comment: @Raphael `input()` returns a string, so the value cannot be some other type such as a boolean.  It could certainly be the literal strings `"True"` or `"False"`, but the OP did not say those needed special handling.

Comment: I think it is better to mention `continue` as well while keeping `break;`

Comment: I tried here in the console and it breaks if the input is `False`. I know the input is a string, but this happens, crazy. Python 2.7 btw since the TAG is `python` and not `python3-x`.

Comment: @Raphael are you using Python 2?  The correct function for accepting keyboard user input in Python 2 is `raw_input()`, not plain `input()`.  This is 2020, Python 2 is history.  `python` tag should assume Python 3.

Comment: I don't use python 2, I tested by mistake and obtained this result. I typed `python` (Python 2.7.5 (default, Aug  4 2017, 00:39:18)) on my console instead of `python3`

Answer (score 0):

```
def populate_list():
    lista=[]
    while True:
        try:
            s_input = raw_input("Enter values: ")
            if not s_input:
                print("INVALID INPUT")
                break
            lista.append(s)
        except EOFError:
            break;
    return list
```